# Applescript + Microsoft Word -- file types for "save as"?

Tags: macos, ms-word, applescript

I am trying to write a script to save a Word document in the single-file webpage (.mht) format.  I am up to the part where I write the actual "save" command, and I'm stuck there.  This is what I am trying to do:

```
# the_file is a variable which has been set here
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    activate
    open the_file
    save the_file as [type]
end tell
```

The open part works just fine.  But I don't know what to put in for the save type.  Perhaps more importantly, I don't know where I can find a list of the available types.  Can anyone help?

EDIT: A commenter suggested the word dictionary; I found the following there but don't know how to interpret it [I'm an AS noob].

```
[file format format document97/‌format document97/‌format template97/‌format template97/‌format text/‌format text line breaks/‌format dostext/‌format dostext line breaks/‌format rtf/‌format Unicode text/‌format Unicode text/‌format HTML/‌format web archive/‌format stationery/‌format xml/‌format document/‌format documentME/‌format template/‌format templateME/‌format PDF/‌format flat document/‌format flat documentME/‌format flat template/‌format flat templateME/‌format custom dictionary/‌format exclude dictionary/‌format documentAuto/‌format templateAuto] : The format in which the document is saved.
```

Comment: The AS dictionary for Word doesn't list the possible values?

Answer (score 2):

Try `format web archive`. Of all the formats listed, that one looks the most likely.

Comment: not what I need.  Looks like I need HTML but with some kind of options; all the other formats are definitely wrong.  HTML is HTML, but with lots of extra stuff I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

1- You must specify a document when using the `save` command, not the **file path**.
For better control, use the `open` command with the property `file name`, it return the document object.

When using this : `open the_file`, it return nothing, in this case you must use `front document`, but it's unreliable, for example if another document opens after.

2- Word does not change the extension when using the `save` command in **Applescript**, the script must replace the extension.
Also, I recommend the command `save as` to have more options instead of `save`.

Answer updated : **format HTML** instead of **Web archive**

```
set the_file to (choose file) 
   tell application "Microsoft Word"
        set thisDoc to open file name (the_file as string)
        set tName to my removeExtension(name of thisDoc)

        -- save in the same directory
    save as thisDoc file format format HTML file name (tName & ".htm") with HTML display only output
        close thisDoc saving no
    end tell

    on removeExtension(t)
        if t does not contain "." then return t
        set tid to text item delimiters
        set text item delimiters to "."
        set t to (text items 1 thru -2 of t) as string
        set text item delimiters to tid
        return t
    end removeExtension
```

If you don't want `HTML display only output`, use `without HTML display only output`